# php ajax comment system doesn't works query doesn't insert anything

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

am using following code for my comment system
when i type comment and name and click on submit button i get nothing **no error or warning doesn't insert anythng** can someone find what's wrong with code

**index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            function sendPost() {
                var comment = document.getElementById("comment").value;
                var name = document.getElementById("username").value;
                if (comment && name) {
                    $.ajax
                    ({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'post_comment.php',
                        data: {
                            user_comm: comment,
                            user_name: name
                        },
                        success: function (response) {
                            console.log(response);
                            document.getElementById("all_comments").innerHTML = response + document.getElementById("all_comments").innerHTML;
                            document.getElementById("comment").value = "";
                            document.getElementById("username").value = "";
                        }
                    });
                }
                return false;
            }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form method='post' action="" onsubmit="return sendPost();">
    <textarea id="comment" name="comment" placeholder="Write Your Comment Here....."></textarea>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Your Name">
    <input type="submit" value="Post Comment">
</form>
<div align="center" id="all_comments">
    <?php
    include_once 'dbConfig.php';
    $comm = $connect->query("select name,comment,post_time from comments order by post_time desc");
    while($row=$comm->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        $name=$row['name'];
        $comment=$row['comment'];
        $time=$row['post_time'];
        ?>
        <div class="comment_div">
            <p class="name">Posted By:<?php echo $name;?></p>
            <p class="comment"><?php echo $comment;?></p>
            <p class="time"><?php echo $time;?></p>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**post_comment.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'dbConfig.php';
if(isset($_POST['user_comm']) && isset($_POST['user_name']))
{
    $comment=$_POST['user_comm'];
    $name=$_POST['user_name'];
    $insert=$connect->query("insert into comments values('','$name','$comment',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");
    $id= $connect->insert_id;
    $select=$connect->query("select name,comment,post_time from comments where name='$name' and comment='$comment' and id='$id'");
    if($row=$select->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        $name=$row['name'];
        $comment=$row['comment'];
        $time=$row['post_time'];
        ?>
        <div class="comment_div">
            <p class="name">Posted By:<?php echo $name;?></p>
            <p class="comment"><?php echo $comment;?></p>
            <p class="time"><?php echo $time;?></p>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    exit;
}
else{
    echo "No Data Is set";
}

?>
```

Comment: Could you try passing `'user_comm': comment, 'user_name': name` inside your `data` of your ajax. And what do you get from your console log? Errors or does it display the `response` data in your console log?

Comment: @LoganWayne tried doesn't help

Comment: @LoganWayne no i dont get anything error or response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
data: {
    "user_comm": comment,
    "user_name": name
}
```

And your insert query is missing the column names:

```
/* JUST REPLACE THE NECESSARY COLUMN NAME */
$insert = $connect->query("INSERT INTO comments (column1, column2, column3, column4) VALUES ('','$name','$comment',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");
```

To further troubleshoot, try displaying any data using `console.log('success');` inside your `success: function(response){}`. If it did not display the `success` message, then your `post_comment.php` has the problem.